# Ansible synchronize always sets changed

Tags: ansible

I need to set the contents of a dest folder to be the same as my src folder.  So I am using the synchronize module:

```
- name: files for /lib/user/ based on the Runtime version
  synchronize:
    src: "/data/managedFiles/lib/{{ runtime.version }}/user/"
    dest: "{{ mule_directory }}{{ mule_runtime_name }}/lib/user/"
    delete: yes
  register: result
```

But this sets "changed" to 'true' in result, even when there was no change.   I need this to be only set to 'true' if there was a something changed because the next task tests for this state.

If I repeat the same synchronize task right after this one it doesn't set 'changed' to 'true'.  But that one always doesn't get set to 'true'.

Subsequent runs of the play with no change to the src ("/data/managedFiles/lib/{{ runtime.version }}/user/") always set result with 'changed'.

Comment: It seems to be worse that that if you use `rsync_opts: ['-q']` to stop it being so verbose! then the task is always 'OK'. and any attached `notify:` requests never gets executed.
So it seems it is doing some sort of 'output parsing'.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the timestamps of the files are included in the test that detects when to copy the files.  Since the files are being pulled from git, the timestamps are different on each play creating a false signal.  But not when the same synchronize is run twice in a row.  The solution is to set checksum parameter to yes so that timestamps are not checked.  But this requires also setting the recursive and archive parameters:

```
- name: files for /lib/user/ based on the Runtime version
  synchronize:
    src: "/data/managedFiles/lib/{{ runtime.version }}/user/"
    dest: "{{ mule_directory }}{{ mule_runtime_name }}/lib/user/"
    recursive: yes
    archive: no
    checksum: yes
    delete: yes
  register: result
```

Comment: Just setting `times: false` intstead of `archive: flase` seems to be enough, but if doing it from a gitlab ansible piepline then you are better off using `archive:false` to avoid permission and ownership changes too.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some pre-condition like this:

---

```
- name: check dest directory exists 
  stat:
     path: {{ mule_directory }}{{ mule_runtime_name }}/lib/user/
  register: exist_dir


- name: files for /lib/user/ based on the Runtime version
  synchronize:
    src: "/data/managedFiles/lib/{{ runtime.version }}/user/"
    dest: "{{ mule_directory }}{{ mule_runtime_name }}/lib/user/"
    delete: yes
  when: not exist_dir.stat.exists
  register: result
```

---

or

```
- name: Check whether {{ runtime.version }} exists somewhere in one of the file
  command: grep -Fxq "{{ runtime.version }}"    "{{ mule_directory }}{{ mule_runtime_name }}/lib/user/"
  register: checkversion
  check_mode: no
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: no

- name: files for /lib/user/ based on the Runtime version
  synchronize:
    src: "/data/managedFiles/lib/{{ runtime.version }}/user/"
    dest: "{{ mule_directory }}{{ mule_runtime_name }}/lib/user/"
    delete: yes
  when: checkversion.rc != 0
```

Comment: The directory {{ mule_directory }}{{ mule_runtime_name }}/lib/user/ will always exist.  It's the contents I'm trying to synchronize.

Comment: What about files in {{ mule_directory }}{{ mule_runtime_name }}/lib/user/ ?

Comment: There are always files in "/data/managedFiles/lib/{{ runtime.version }}/user/", the dest will be empty the very first time the play is run. Dest is correctly populated and if a file is removed from src it will be removed from dest (the effect of delete: yes). So I'm getting the correct results except for the changed state.